# SUM function breaks query with columns containing no numerical values

Tags: sql, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So at my work we inspect tires, and I'm building a sheet to input each day's inspections so that I can see a monthly view.

I have a query in cell A7 in my "Monthly Report" sheet/tab that works, but it breaks with `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC` if one of the columns in the query doesn't contain any numerical values amongst their rows.

My query is
`=QUERY({'1st'!A7:D;'2nd'!A7:D}, "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4) GROUP BY Col1")`

I've read from a similar post I should be using the n() function but haven't been able to get the syntax to work. I'm really pushing my limits on google sheet knowledge so any education/help would be lovely.

A simplified copy of the sheet is below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bmfV59hfWcCYOlWQmdjRKcKhNl1hj9O_1IaZrGm6fAY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can't sum non numeric data, so check those 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

You need use CASE statement inside SUM function to check if value is numeric or not.

```
SELECT Col1, SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Col2)=1 THEN Col2 ELSE 0.00 END), 
SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Col3)=1 THEN Col3 ELSE 0.00 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Col4)=1 THEN Col4 ELSE 0.00 END) GROUP BY Col1;
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I am getting ```Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "WHEN "" at line 1, column 23. Was expecting: ")" ...```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=QUERY({{'1st'!A7:A,ARRAYFORMULA(N('1st'!B7:B)),ARRAYFORMULA(N('1st'!C7:C)),ARRAYFORMULA(N('1st'!D7:D))};{'2nd'!A7:A,ARRAYFORMULA(N('2nd'!B7:B)),ARRAYFORMULA(N('2nd'!C7:C)),ARRAYFORMULA(N('2nd'!D7:D))}},"SELECT Col1, SUM(Col2), SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4) GROUP BY Col1")
```

Although this works for ignoring non-numerical values, all blank cells have a 0, which can be fixed by applying a conditional formatting like below (this is solely for hiding the "0" values):

[image]

**Output:**

[image]